# comparing a specific character to a string

Tags: c, string

I'm using array of strings soo when trying to compare a character str[x][y] it is comparing with the first letter of string x i.e str[x].

```
for(x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(y=0;y<n;y++)
        {
            if(x!=y)
            {
                if(str[x][y]=='c')
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            printf("%c\n",str[x][y]);
        }
```

while printing it is giving the correct value but while comparing it is taking the whole string, and only the first character of the string is compared.

Comment: Your code says "if this condition then *do nothing*, but also add one to count regardless".

Answer (score 2):

Your code says "if this condition then *do nothing*, but also add one to count regardless". Remember a `;` is used to terminate a statement, so in the case of `if` you don't put one, you're not done yet.

Try and code your `if` statements like this:

```
if(str[x][y]=='c') {
  count++;
}
```

Comment: oh my god I've tried some other stuff and probably forgot to remove the semi colon.

Comment: If I see code that "isn't working" and it has an egregious error like this that makes the code behave in a completely incorrect way then that's the first thing to fix. If there's still problems you're going to have to show how this code is used. There's no use-case in your example, so we're not sure how to engage that function properly.

Comment: It'd help if this example was more complete. There's a two-dimensional array structure at work here, which is confusing things. It's ideal if you produce something small that [we can compile and experiment with to fix your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: so I'm using loops like 2d array if I want to know the character at a position I'm using  str[x][y] unlike array I'm not getting the element at that position but the whole string at x

Comment: Are you testing for one character, or more than one character at a time? You can always use a `switch` inside a loop for more than one possible match.

Comment: The question I'm trying to do: There are 'n' number of employees in an office they should be divided in groups of two to form a team. if n is odd the remaining one will be a one man team. The input will be n number of strings with c's and x's. Two employees i,j (0<i,j<n)are compatible(if i!=j and i=j=c)and otherwise (if i!=j, if i=j=x) the team with one member can handle the load if(i=j) and i=j=c and otherwise if i=j=x... my idea is to count the compatibility for every employee and start teaming up with the lowest one.

Comment: sample input: 3 ccx cxx xxx

Comment: That description helps a lot. You may want to open up a new question with that detail, and close this one out as related to the syntax error that's now fixed.

Comment: But Im not allowed to ask another question it seems If you get any solution please comment Thank you.